# Rust VSCode Docs of private lib not available

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-analyzer

I've got a private lib stored on GitHub I'm using on my project.
For some reason the docs for this lib are not loaded in VSCode, so they are not displayed when hovering over the documented method.

In my `Cargo.toml` the lib is added like this:

```
[dependencies]
private_lib = { git = "https://github.com/my_account_name/private_lib.git" }
```

It works so the dependency should be right, do have to do something else, so the docs are loaded as well?

Comment: Does it say nothing when you hover, or "Loading..."?

Comment: It's just displaying something like `extern crate private_lib` or the basic information about the function.

Comment: Can you attach an image?

Comment: the problem changed, in my workspace I've got multiple folders with different crates/projects inside. In one project the docs are displayed, in the other not.